# Which method is called by default while the application open every time?

Tags: iphone

i have done the small animation in my first view.I called it in viewDidLoad method.If i close and open the application,i couldnt see the animation because the view was already loaded in to the memory.So i want the method that will call every time while application starts without run.

Help me

Comment: Are you building your project against SDK 4? If so your application may be multitasking and that's the likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much clear what you want to achieve, could you post some code?
BTW, Have you tried to place it in `viewWillAppear:` ?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` won't (necessarily) fire if the application is returning from the background.

Comment: @BoltClock, you are right, I did not realized it could be a multitasking issue